# Using Field.index from apache lucene index

Tags: apache, lucene, indexer

I am attempting to implement a simple lucene index, using Lucene 7.1.
There are allot of changes to the code between versions, so I am meeting a lot of changes from answer to answer.

In this tutorial I am following 
https://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-lucene-to-index-and-search-text-files.html

There is a line 
document.add(new Field(FIELD_PATH, path, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
However Field.Index is throwing up errors. I can convert it to TextField but I am not sure if this is the same thing. Can anyone tell me what Field.Index does and how one could modify the code so that it will run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is using 2.3, it's so old the folks at apache don't even keep that version of lucene in the archives. It wouldn't bother with a resource that old, more headache than it's worth. Looks like they're mostly just going through the lucene demo that comes with every released version of lucene, though. Try going through the [current Lucene demo](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/demo/overview-summary.html), instead.

As far as what to replace that exact field with, it's indexed, stored and not tokenized, so you'll want to use a [StringField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html). A TextField would be for a field that *is* tokenized.